# Changing "Starting Position" of a fixed css element

Tags: position, fixed

I'm a newbie to html and css, and I was wondering if this is possible in pure css.

So I made 3 divs, all fitted perfectly to my screen size. What I am wondering is if you make the "Menu" fixed so it scrolls along, can you change the starting position of it?

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue">
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

This is the CSS that goes along with it:

```
.red{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
}


h1{
  font-size: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

So what I basically mean is can "Menu" be fixed from when I scroll across the blue div and downwards while it's not visible yet on the red div? (so the 'starting position' of it is actually on the blue div)

Sorry if the question is poorly explained, english is not my native language. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean that once the blue div appears while scrolling, the menu jumps to it and leave the red div ?

Comment: I mean that the 'Menu' will appear with the blue div and so on, but when you scroll back to the red div, it will stick to the blue one again, so when the page loads, 'menu' won't be visible untill the blue div appears.

Comment: you want the menu to be appear only in the blue region, right ?

Comment: Basically every Div except the red one actually. See it like the red div would be an introduction panel, and when you scroll down the menu will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you mentioned you want the solution in pure css, but if you would like to use JQuery that will be a solution.

make the menu absolute:

```
.persist-menu
{
   position: absolute;
}
```

right a function to update the position of the menu

```
function UpdateMenuPosition() {
       var el             =  $(".blue"),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".persist-menu", el)

       if (scrollTop > offset.top) {
           floatingHeader.css({top:(scrollTop)});
       } else {

       };
}
```

and call it while scrolling

```
$(function() {

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateMenuPosition)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

Check the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wfff74w9/4/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. However, I don't know (yet) how to load JQuery into my html document.

Comment: you are welcome :) you can download the jquery file from here [download](http://jquery.com/download/)
then add this tag in the header of your html `<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I know I probably sound stupid right now, but do I copy the code into a script tag in html or do I save the script to a .js file?

Comment: ask whatever you like.. we all ask basic questions in the areas we didn't experience before.. regarding your question both approaches are correct and since the code is simple so both will work fine

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide "Menu" on red and green divs using z-index.

CSS:

```
.red{
background-color: red;
width: 100%;
height: 1080px;
z-index:3;
position: relative; 
}
.blue{
background-color: blue;
width: 100%;
height: 1080px;
z-index:1;
}
.green{
background-color: green;
width: 100%;
height: 1080px;
z-index:3;
position: relative; 
}
h1{
font-size: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index:2;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3k3wyscL/

But with this solution problematically would be to add another text visible only on red or green div.

Edit: as you want to see "Menu" on green div too, you can delete green class z-index and position parameters in css.